# Collection was modified when adding to collection

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, collections

Getting the "Collection was modified" exception when attempting to add to a collection

```
public void UpdateLinks(EventViewModel form)
{
    var selectedIds = form.Links.Select(r => r.ResourceTypeID).ToList();
    var assignedIds = form.Event.Links.Select(r => r.ResourceTypeID).ToList();
    foreach (var resource in form.Links)
    {
        resource.EventID = form.Event.ID;
        if (!assignedIds.Contains(resource.ResourceTypeID))
            form.Event.Links.Add(resource);
    }
    foreach (var resource in form.Event.Links.ToList())
    {
        if (!selectedIds.Contains(resource.ResourceTypeID))
            form.Event.Links.Remove(resource);
    }
}
```

The problem is specifically with the "Add" method. If I comment that part out, no exception is thrown. It's important to note that I've already tried re-writing the foreach as a for loop and adding "ToList()" to form.Links. The same exception is thrown in all cases. I use this exact pattern on other parts of the site without issue which is why this is so frustrating. This also works on "Create". The problem only affects the "Edit" action.

Other relevant code:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(EventViewModel form, HttpPostedFileBase[] eventFiles)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        eventsService.UpdateEvent(form.Event);
        eventsService.UpdateManufacturerTags(form);
        eventsService.UpdateFiles(form, eventFiles);
        eventsService.UpdateLinks(form);
        eventsService.Save();
        return RedirectToAction("Details", new { id = form.Event.ID });
    }
    return View(form);
}

public class EventViewModel : ContentLeftViewModel
{
    public Event Event { get; set; }
    public string[] SelectedManufacturers { get; set; }
    public MultiSelectList Manufacturers { get; set; }
    public IList<EventResource> Files { get; set; }
    public IList<EventResource> Links { get; set; }

    public EventViewModel()
    {
        SelectedManufacturers = new string[0];
        Files = new List<EventResource>();
        Links = new List<EventResource>();
    }
}

public class Event
{
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Title { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DisplayName("Start Time")]
    [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:M/d/yyyy h:mm tt}")]
    public DateTime? StartTime { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DisplayName("End Time")]
    [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:M/d/yyyy h:mm tt}")]
    public DateTime? EndTime { get; set; }

    public string Venue { get; set; }

    public string Address { get; set; }

    public string City { get; set; }

    public string State { get; set; }

    public string Zip { get; set; }

    [AllowHtml]
    [DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]
    public string Description { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Registration Link")]
    public string RegistrationUrl { get; set; }

    public virtual IList<Manufacturer> Manufacturers { get; set; }

    public virtual IList<EventResource> Files { get; set; }

    public virtual IList<EventResource> Links { get; set; }

    //public IEnumerable<EventResource> Resources
    //{
    //    get { return Files.Concat(Links); }
    //}

    public string StartDate
    {
        get { return StartTime.Value.ToShortDateString(); }
    }

    public string StartTimeOnly
    {
        get { return StartTime.Value.ToShortTimeString(); }
    }

    public string EndDate
    {
        get { return EndTime.Value.ToShortDateString(); }
    }

    public string EndTimeOnly
    {
        get { return EndTime.Value.ToShortTimeString(); }
    }

    public Event()
    {
        Manufacturers = new List<Manufacturer>();
        Files = new List<EventResource>();
        Links = new List<EventResource>();
    }
}

public class EventResource
{
    [Key, Column(Order = 0)]
    public int EventID { get; set; }

    [Key, Column(Order = 1)]
    public int ResourceTypeID { get; set; }

    [Key, Column(Order = 2)]
    public string Path { get; set; }

    public virtual Event Event { get; set; }

    public virtual ResourceType Type { get; set; }
}
```

**UPDATE**

Some more info: Adding to the collection at all... even outside of a loop throws the same error. Does that give anyone an idea?

Comment: it's not recommended to modify the collection when you are iterating through a foreach.see if a simple for loop fits the purpose

Comment: Every .Net collection will throw an exception if you try to modify it while iterating through it - doesn't matter if it's a for-each loop or if you got the iterator and are doing it "by hand" (in a for- or while-loop). Either try using a For-Loop as suggested above, or create a temporary collection with the data you want to remove or add afterwards.

Comment: On other parts of the site, I have used the same solution successfully with different types of entities. You're correct, but adding the "ToList()" to create a new list to avoid that problem had been enough in these other cases. I will try out the suggestions below.

Comment: Also, as stated in the original post, I have already tried rewriting the foreach as a simple for loop. I get the same exception either way.

Comment: Want to also emphasize that the code as is works perfectly on Create. Removing items this way works on Edit too. The problem is specifically with the add portion of this method when executed on Edit. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
var lsEvents = form.Event.Links.ToList();
foreach (var resource in form.Links)
{
    resource.EventID = form.Event.ID;
    if (!assignedIds.Contains(resource.ResourceTypeID))
        lsEvents.Add(resource);
}
foreach (var resource in form.Event.Links)
{
    if (!selectedIds.Contains(resource.ResourceTypeID))
        lsEvents.Remove(resource);
}
```

and Use `lsEvents` according to the requirement. This will fix your issue.

Comment: With this method, it requires you to also set form.Event.Links to lsEvents if you actually want the change reflected in the model. Once you do that, the same exception is thrown. Pretty stuck on this!

Answer (score 0):

You can use LINQ to filter out entries before adding them.

```
public void UpdateLinks(EventViewModel form)
{
    var selectedIds = form.Links.Select(r => r.ResourceTypeID).ToArray();
    var assignedIds = form.Event.Links.Select(r => r.ResourceTypeID).ToArray();
    foreach (var resource in form.Links
        .Where(r=> !assignedIds.Contain(r.ResourceTypeID)).ToArray())
    {
        resource.EventID = form.Event.ID;
        form.Event.Links.Add(resource);
    }
    foreach (var resource in form.Event.Links
        .Where(r=> !selectedIds.Contain(r.ResourceTypeID)).ToArray())
    {
        form.Event.Links.Remove(resource);
    }
}
```

In both methods, we are filtering resources before enumerating and adding. You can not enumerate and add at the same time.

Comment: Gave this a shot but the same exception was thrown

Comment: Try now with ToList changed to ToArray

Comment: How about now? I have made every To List to To Array. what is form. Links's type? Is it a list or some other collection type?

Comment: form is an EventViewModel which contains an Event Model object and other collections used to compare posted form collection values to current collection values so that updates can be made to account for those items added to the collections and those removed from them. For example, form.Links contains what form.Event.Links should be modified to match.

Comment: Unfortunately that latest change didn't make a difference either. Whether you make the temporary collection an array or a list shouldn't matter so I'm not surprised that it didn't make a difference but I wanted to try it out anyway. This is extremely confusing because like I mentioned in the original post, I have used this exact collection update pattern with other entities on the site without issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can't modify a collection you are enumerating (e.g., for each).

You need to loop once to get the items you want to add and/or remove, then add or remove all of them in a second loop outside the first.

E.g.:

```
Dim coll = New List(of String)({"1", "2", "3", "4", "6"})
dim coll2 = New List(of String)({"5", "8", "9", "2"})

Dim removeItems as new list(of String)()

For Each item in coll
 For Each item2 in coll2
  If item2 = item
    removeItems.Add(item)
  end if
 Next item2
Next item

' remove the items gathered
For each itemToRemove in removeItems
 coll.Remove(itemToRemove)
Next itemToRemove
```

It can be done a better way, but this shows the gist of the error.  You can't change the collection you are looping over.

Comment: Tried this and same

            foreach (var resource in form.Links)
            {
                resource.EventID = form.Event.ID;
                if (!assignedIds.Contains(resource.ResourceTypeID))
                    addedLinks.Add(resource);
            }
            foreach (var resource in form.Event.Links.ToList())
            {
                if (!selectedIds.Contains(resource.ResourceTypeID))
                    removedLinks.Add(resource);
            }
            removedLinks.ForEach(r => form.Event.Links.Remove(r));
            addedLinks.ForEach(r => form.Event.Links.Add(r));

Answer (score 0):

Not sure exactly what was responsible for solving the issue, but after upgrading to Visual Studio 2013 Express (from 2010 Professional), and installing ASP.Net 4.5/IIS8 with it, even though this application continues to target ASP.Net 4.0, I am no longer experiencing the issue and the code used in the original post works as is.

Perhaps this was caused by a certain build of the ASP.Net framework or an older version of IIS?